# Customization of horizontal bar chart using SFCartesian in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, bar-chart

I have created a horizontal bar chart using SFCartesian like shown below:
[image]

The code that I have used is as follows,

```
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';
class Chart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChartState createState() => _ChartState();
}

class _ChartState extends State<Chart> {
  late List<Data> _chartData;
  @override
  void initState(){
    _chartData = getChartData();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    ....
    ....
    SfCartesianChart(
      series: <ChartSeries> [
       BarSeries<Data, String> (
       dataSource: _chartData,
       xValueMapper: (Data exp, _) => exp.abc,
       yValueMapper: (Data exp, _) => exp.xyz,
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(right: Radius.circular(10.0)),
       width: 0.2,
       color: Colors.amber,
       ),
        ],
       primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
       title: ChartTitle(
              text: 'Example',
               ),
             ),
        );//Scaffold
  }
  List <Data> getChartData(){
    final List<Data> chartData = [
      Data('A', 580),
      Data('B', 350),
      Data('C', 250),
    ];
    return chartData;
  }
}

class Data{
  Data(this.abc, this.xyz);
  final String abc;
  final double xyz;
}
```

The first thing I want to customize in this is the x-axis range. I want the range to be 0, 150, 300, 450, 600. The second customization required is that I want to assign different colors to each one of the bar, like pink to A, blue to B and amber to C. I have searched many materials to find customizations, but didn't find these. Any help will really be very useful, thanks in advance!